# Couldn't able to run the mapreduce program on HIPI Hadoop Image processing interface?

Tags: hadoop

I am trying to install the hipi onto hadoop, after installing when I was trying to run the downloader with the command ant downloader, am getting the below error.

downloader:

setup:

test_settings:

compile: [javac] Compiling 3 source files to /home/sam/hipi_1/bin [javac] /home/sam/hipi_1/examples/hipi/examples/downloader/Downloader.java:3: error: package hipi.image.ImageHeader does not exist [javac] import hipi.image.ImageHeader.ImageType; [javac] ^ [javac] /home/sam/hipi_1/examples/hipi/examples/downloader/Downloader.java:4: error: package hipi.imagebundle does not exist [javac] import hipi.imagebundle.HipiImageBundle; [javac] ^ [javac] /home/sam/hipi_1/examples/hipi/examples/downloader/Downloader.java:61: error: cannot find symbol [javac] HipiImageBundle hib = new HipiImageBundle(new Path(temp_path), conf); [javac] ^ [javac] symbol: class HipiImageBundle [javac] location: class DownloaderMapper [javac] /home/sam/hipi_1/examples/hipi/examples/downloader/Downloader.java:61: error: cannot find symbol [javac] HipiImageBundle hib = new HipiImageBundle(new Path(temp_path), conf);

Answer (score 1):

You first download [HIPI Library Release 0.1.0](http://hipi.cs.virginia.edu/downloads/hipi-0.1.0.jar) and put in the main directory of HIPI then find build.xml in the main directory of HIPI and change:

```
<target name="compile" depends="setup, test_settings">
<mkdir dir="bin" />
<!-- Compile -->
<javac nowarn="on" includeantruntime="no" srcdir="${srcdir}" destdir="./bin" classpath="${hadoop.classpath}:./src/hipi.jar" />
<!-- Create the jar -->
<jar destfile="${jardir}/${jarfilename}" basedir="./bin">
  <zipfileset src="./src/hipi.jar" />
  <manifest>
    <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${mainclass}" />
  </manifest>
</jar>
```

to:

```
<target name="compile" depends="setup, test_settings">
<mkdir dir="bin" />
<!-- Compile -->
<javac nowarn="on" includeantruntime="no" srcdir="${srcdir}" destdir="./bin" classpath="${hadoop.classpath}:hipi-0.1.0.jar" />
<!-- Create the jar -->
<jar destfile="${jardir}/${jarfilename}" basedir="./bin">
  <zipfileset src="hipi-0.1.0.jar" />
  <manifest>
    <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${mainclass}" />
  </manifest>
</jar>
```

Good Luck